# How do I move a file from current directory in Perl?

Tags: perl

Hello all who may assist. I have a problem which I seem not t understand. I am selecting files and combining them with a "cdo" command after combining, I want to move the combined files into another directory.
This worked perfectly a month ago, then I had to increase ram, which took a month to do with no work done on the script.
Here is the start of my script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Copy qw(move);
use Path::Tiny;
use Tie::File;
use File::Cat;
```

Before I come to the problem, the following move command works after selecting a file

```
              print "Copying $file\n" if $debug;
              my $cmd01 = "cp $Input_Data_Dirs[$ll]/$file  $Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]";
              print "Doing system ($cmd01)\n" if $debug;
              system ($cmd01);
```

So am able to move several files with the above construction, then I move into the directory. From there I combine six files into one

```
      print "doing cat with cdo\n" if $debug;
      my $cmd05 = "cdo cat @sixfiles $newfile";
      print "Doing system ($cmd05)\n" if $debug;
      system ($cmd05);
```

Here is the part which fails

```
#-----------------------------------------
      #print "Moving combined file\n" if $debug;
      #my $cmd21 = "cp $newfile  $Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk]";
      #print "Doing system ($cmd21)\n" if $debug;
      #system ($cmd21);
      #copy $newfile, $Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk];
      move $newfile, $Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk];
      #----------------------------------------------------
```

The unix commands "cp" and "mv" give the error

```
cp: missing destination file operand after 'pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19710101_20001231.nc'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
sh: 2: /home/suman/CORDEX/DATA/historical/precip: Permission denied
```

and

```
mv: missing destination file operand after 'pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19710101_20001231.nc'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
sh: 2: /home/suman/CORDEX/DATA/historical/precip: Permission denied
```

I have made sure there is no permission problem by issuing the command

```
sudo chmod -Rv ugo +rwx CORDEX
```

On the other hand the perl in-built commands "copy" and "move" give the following errors

```
    Argument "precip" isn't numeric in division (/) at merge_files.pl line 247.
Argument "/home/suman/CORDEX/DATA/historical" isn't numeric in division (/) at merge_files.pl line 247.
Illegal division by zero at merge_files.pl line 247.
```

I am really defeated by these errors.
I will appreciate any assistance if ever possible to resolve this

I have upvoted the solution from Dave Cross for the reason that it eliminates the error of non-numeric/division by zero. Thanks Dave for that.
However, after defining

```
my $target_dir="$Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk]";
```

both the commands:

```
my $cmd21 = "cp -v $newfile --target-directory=$target_dir";
```

and
     my $cmd21 = "mv -v $newfile --target-directory=$target_dir"

give the same error

```
    cp: missing destination file operand after 'pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19710101_20001231.nc'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
sh: 2: --target-directory=/home/suman/CORDEX/DATA/historical/precip: not found
```

yet the target_dir exists.
The two perl commands

```
      copy $newfile, "$target_dir" or die "copy operation failed: $!";
      move $newfile, "$target_dir" or die "move operation failed: $!";
move operation failed: No such file or directory at merge_files.pl line 249.
copy operation failed: No such file or directory at merge_files.pl line 248.
```

I am really baffled.

Comment: I find `print()` an invaluable tool when working on problems like this. Print the various strings just before the failing statements. If you're using `system()` then print out the whole command before running it. You can even copy it and try running the same command at the bash prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> move $newfile, $Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk];
> ```

This is wrong. When combining two variables like this, you need to put them in a string.

```
move $newfile, "$Output_Base_Dirs[$mm]/$Var_Dirs[$kk]";
```

Without that, Perl thinks you're trying to do a division sum.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cross, I will give you feedback when I try this in about 12 hours from now

Comment: I have upvoted Dave Cross's solution for the reason that it get rid of the non-numeric/division by zero error. Otherwise my problem persists as per my edits in the main post.